# How do I determine how many characters in common two pandas columns have?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `dataframe` with two columns. I want to know how many characters they have in common. The number of common elements should be a new column. Here's a minimally reproducible example.

**What I have:**

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_lowercase
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[''.join(np.random.choice(list(ascii_lowercase), 
                8)) for i in range(10)] for i in range(2)], 
                  index=['col_1', 'col_2']).T
```

```
Out[17]: 
      col_1     col_2
0  ollcgfmy  daeubsrx
1  jtvtqoux  xbgtrzno
2  irwmoqqa  mdblczfa
3  jyebzpyd  xwlynkhw
4  ifuqojvs  lxotbsju
5  fybsqbku  xwbluaek
6  oylztnpf  gelonsay
7  zdkibutk  ujlcwhfu
8  uhrcjbsk  nhxhpoii
9  eocxreqz  muvfwusi
```

**What I need (the numbers are random):**

```
Out[19]: 
      col_1     col_2  common_letters
0  ollcgfmy  daeubsrx               1
1  jtvtqoux  xbgtrzno               1
2  irwmoqqa  mdblczfa               0
3  jyebzpyd  xwlynkhw               3
4  ifuqojvs  lxotbsju               3
5  fybsqbku  xwbluaek               3
6  oylztnpf  gelonsay               3
7  zdkibutk  ujlcwhfu               3
8  uhrcjbsk  nhxhpoii               1
9  eocxreqz  muvfwusi               3
```

**EDIT:** to anyone reading this trying to get similarity between two strings, don't use this approach. other similarity measures exist, such as levenshtein or jaccard.

Comment: unique characters, or would one column with `mm` and another with `mmm` count as 2?

Comment: yes that is exact

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `df.apply` and `set` operations can be one way to solve the problem:

```
df["common_letters"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: len(set(x["col_1"]).intersection(set(x["col_2"]))),
    axis=1)
```

output:

```
      col_1     col_2  common_letters
0  cgeabfem  amnwfsde               4
1  vozgpmgs  slfwvjnv               2
2  xyvktrfr  jtzijmud               1
3  piexmmgh  ydaxbmyo               2
4  iydpnwcu  hhdxyptd               3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like sets you can go for:

```
df['common_letters'] = (df.col_1.apply(set).apply(len) 
                        + df.col_2.apply(set).apply(len)
                        - (df.col_1+df.col_2).apply(set).apply(len))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy`:

```py
df["noCommonChars"]=np.bitwise_and(df["col_1"].map(set), df["col_2"].map(set)).str.len()
```

Output:

```py
      col_1     col_2  noCommonChars
0  smuxucyw  hywtedvz              2
1  bniuqhkh  axcuukjg              2
2  ttzehrtl  nbmsmwsc              0
3  ndwyjusu  dssmdnvb              3
4  zqvsvych  wguthcwu              2
5  jlnpjqgn  xgedmodm              1
6  ocjbtnpy  lywjqkjf              2
7  tolrpshi  hslxxmgo              4
8  ehatmryw  fhpvluvq              1
9  icciebte  joyiwooi              1
```

**Edit**
In order to include repeating characters - you can do:

```py
from collections import Counter

df["common_letters_full"]=np.bitwise_and(df["col_1"].map(Counter), df["col_2"].map(Counter))
df["common_letters"]=df["common_letters_full"].map(dict.values).apply(sum)
#alternatively:
df["common_letters"]=df["common_letters_full"].apply(pd.Series).sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I already see better answers :D , but here goes a kind of good one. I might have been able to use more from pandas:

I took some code from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-common-characters-in-two-strings/)

```
import pandas as pd
from string import ascii_lowercase
import numpy as np


def countPairs(s1, s2) :  

    n1 = len(s1) ; 
    n2 = len(s2);  

    # To store the frequencies of characters  
    # of string s1 and s2  
    freq1 = [0] * 26;  
    freq2 = [0] * 26;  

    # To store the count of valid pairs  
    count = 0;  

    # Update the frequencies of  
    # the characters of string s1  
    for i in range(n1) :  
        freq1[ord(s1[i]) - ord('a')] += 1;  

    # Update the frequencies of  
    # the characters of string s2  
    for i in range(n2) : 
        freq2[ord(s2[i]) - ord('a')] += 1;  

    # Find the count of valid pairs  
    for i in range(26) : 
        count += min(freq1[i], freq2[i]);  

    return count;  

# This code is contributed by Ryuga 


df = pd.DataFrame([[''.join(np.random.choice(list(ascii_lowercase), 
                8)) for i in range(10)] for i in range(2)], 
                  index=['col_1', 'col_2']).T

counts =  []
for i in range(0,df.shape[0]):
    counts.append(countPairs(df.iloc[i].col_1,df.iloc[i].col_2))

df["counts"] = counts 

      col_1     col_2  counts
0  ploatffk  dwenjpmc       1
1  gjjupyqg  smqtlmzc       1
2  cgtxexho  hvwhpyfh       1
3  mifsbfhc  ufalhlbi       4
4  qnjesfdn  lyhrrnkf       2
5  omnumzmf  dagttzqo       2
6  gsygkrrb  aocfoqxk       1
7  wrgvruuw  ydnlzvyf       1
8  ivkdxoft  zmgcnrjr       0
9  vvthbzjj  mmirlcvx       1
```